# jquery accordion effect

Tags: jquery, load, horizontal-accordion

I've been working for some time to understand why a JavaScript horizontal accordion plugin doesnt work when I load it as html into one div using `.load()`.

The accordion extends out beyond the div not showing in a row.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1; this plugin was created for 1.3.2, but I don't know if that is causing the problem.

css

```
#content_ac {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:300px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px solid #99cc33;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#content_ac').load("prod_ind_present.html");
});
<script>
```

prod_ind_present.html:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .accordionWrapper{display:inline-block; background-color:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
    .accordionWrapper img{vertical-align:top; border:0; margin:0; padding:0}
    .accordionWrapper div{display:inline; float:left; margin:auto;}
    .accordionWrapper div.title{cursor:pointer;}
    .accordionWrapper div.contentt{display:none;}
    .set{border-bottom:1px solid #000}
    .set1{background-color:#C77B3F;}
    .set2{background-color:#FFC732;}
    .set3{background-color:#007C90;}
    .set4{background-color:#AD6F08;}
    .set5{background-color:#387855;}
    .set6{background-color:#8C4B2D;}
    .set7{background-color:#82A668;}
    </style>
    <div class="set set1">
        <div class="title"><img src="images/menu1-h.jpg" width="30" height="198" /></div>
        <div class="contentt"><img src="images/menu-img-1.jpg" width="486" height="198" /></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="set set7">
        <div class="title"><img src="images/menu7-h.jpg" width="30" height="198" /></div>
        <div class="contentt"><img src="images/menu-img-7.jpg" width="486" height="198" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#accordion1").msAccordion({defaultid:3, autodelay:4});
    });
    </script>
```

The result is that in `#content_ac`, which has a auto width property, the sets of accordion divs extends out of bounds of the divs, pushing other content down.

The plugin:

```
//menu Accordion
//author: Marghoob Suleman
//Date: 05th Aug, 2009
//Version: 1.0
//web: www.giftlelo.com | www.marghoobsuleman.com
;(function($){
    $.fn.msAccordion = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({
                    currentDiv:'1',
                    previousDiv:'',
                    vertical: false,
                    defaultid:0,
                    currentcounter:0,
                    intervalid:0,
                    autodelay:0,
                    event:"click",
                    alldivs_array:new Array()
            }, options);
        $(this).addClass("accordionWrapper");
        $(this).css({overflow:"hidden"});
        //alert(this);
        var elementid = $(this).attr("id");
        var allDivs = this.children();
        if(options.autodelay>0)  {
            $("#"+ elementid +" > div").live("mouseenter", function(){
                                                           pause();
                                                           });
            $("#"+ elementid +" > div").live("mouseleave", function(){
                                                                  startPlay();
                                                                  });
        }
        //set ids
        allDivs.each(function(current) {
                                 var iCurrent = current;
                                 var sTitleID = elementid+"_msTitle_"+(iCurrent);
                                 var sContentID = sTitleID+"_msContent_"+(iCurrent);
                                 var currentDiv = allDivs[iCurrent];
                                 var totalChild = currentDiv.childNodes.length;
                                 var titleDiv = $(currentDiv).find("div.title");
                                 titleDiv.attr("id", sTitleID);
                                 var contentDiv = $(currentDiv).find("div.content");
                                 contentDiv.attr("id", sContentID);
                                 options.alldivs_array.push(sTitleID);
                                 //$("#"+sTitleID).click(function(){openMe(sTitleID);});
                                 $("#"+sTitleID).bind(options.event, function(){pause();openMe(sTitleID);});
                                 });

        //make vertical
        if(options.vertical) {makeVertical();};
        //open default
        openMe(elementid+"_msTitle_"+options.defaultid);
        if(options.autodelay>0) {startPlay();};
        //alert(allDivs.length);
        function openMe(id) {
            var sTitleID = id;
            var iCurrent = sTitleID.split("_")[sTitleID.split("_").length-1];
            options.currentcounter = iCurrent;
            var sContentID = id+"_msContent_"+iCurrent;
            if($("#"+sContentID).css("display")=="none") {
                if(options.previousDiv!="") {
                    closeMe(options.previousDiv);
                };
                if(options.vertical) {
                    $("#"+sContentID).slideDown("slow");
                } else {
                    $("#"+sContentID).show("slow");
                }
                options.currentDiv = sContentID;
                options.previousDiv = options.currentDiv;
            };
        };
        function closeMe(div) {
            if(options.vertical) {
                $("#"+div).slideUp("slow");
            } else {
                $("#"+div).hide("slow");
            };
        };  
        function makeVertical() {
            $("#"+elementid +" > div").css({display:"block", float:"none", clear:"both"});
            $("#"+elementid +" > div > div.title").css({display:"block", float:"none", clear:"both"});
            $("#"+elementid +" > div > div.content").css({clear:"both"});
        };
        function startPlay() {
            options.intervalid = window.setInterval(play, options.autodelay*1000);
        };
        function play() {
            var sTitleId = options.alldivs_array[options.currentcounter];
            openMe(sTitleId);
            options.currentcounter++;
            if(options.currentcounter==options.alldivs_array.length) options.currentcounter = 0;
        };
        function pause() {
            window.clearInterval(options.intervalid);
        };
        }
})(jQuery);
```

I load that html into div in an html page, which has several other divs too. But it's not showing correctly.

[Here is a screen capture](http://www.dielecsur.com/storage/screen.jpg) showing the problem.

Comment: if i write the whole code in one html file and I load directly in browser, it works but NOT if I load by .load function into a div

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking in your test web in dielecsur.com and I think that the problem is about de class 'content' in the div that has the image. This class has asigned a size by css that makes it to work that way.

Comment: although it works fine i've changed the div which accordion effect will load, 'cause the problem is left property

Comment: I supose you have changed it in all the divs that have the images in the accordion...¿isn't it?

Comment: change? what? auto width property?? yes it is

Comment: at first time you click in industria section under productos menu it works fine, but when you are in industria section and if you click at one opcion in left menu and click again in industria at top of menu is when problem appairs.