# jquery accordion effect clearinterval error

Tags: jquery, accordion, clearinterval

there's any bad thing getting timer in accordion script i'm using because when it starts and user go to another section in webpage, it's still working background. And if the user click in that function again it gets out out bounds.

A friend of mine told me I must put some code to prevent, but it doesnt work.

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( window.accIId ) {
        window.clearInterval( window.accIId );
    }
    $("#accordion1").msAccordion({defaultid:0, autodelay:4});
})
```

accordion.js

```
    function startPlay() {
        options.intervalid = window.setInterval(play, options.autodelay*1000);
        window.accIId = options.intervalid;
    };
    function play() {
        var sTitleId = options.alldivs_array[options.currentcounter];
        openMe(sTitleId);
        options.currentcounter++;
        if(options.currentcounter==options.alldivs_array.length) options.currentcounter = 0;
    };
    function pause() {
        window.clearInterval(options.intervalid);
    };
```

What's te function for stopping ???

[here's the post with first question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014156/jquery-accordion-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval` not `clearInteval`

Comment: ok. sorry for that but there's a lot code and my eyes seems to see in 6dimensions. But even if I write that correctly I have the same problem because divs drop down.